# Merge local Java project to existing git repo

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, git

I have checked out the source from a git repo, because i was forced to use someone elses svn repo for a while, and now i want to re-check in my source in the original git repo. We are using eclipse (STS) for the project. The perfect solution would be to check in the changes made during this time into a new branch and then putting back together everything.
Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your changes made in one folder, you can use that folder as a working tree in order for your git repo to detect and add those changes.

```
cd /path/to/git/repo
git --work-tree=/path/to/other/repo status
git --work-tree=/path/to/other/repo add .
```

Then you can commit and push normally from your git repo now updated with the latest changes from the other repo.

Note: that is a command-line solution: once done, you can resume working in Eclipse.

Comment: The problem is, that the other project is just a java project. It's not a git repo at all.

Comment: @dieTasse exactly: that solution applies even if the other project is not under git at all. The goal is for your git repo to consider another file tree (like the other project) *as if* it was its own git repo working tree. That is what the `--working-tree=...` is for.